# Ruby Rspec should_not_receive not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

For this below code snippet:

```ruby
@by_hidden.should_not_receive(:by_limit).with(100).and_return(@by_limit)
```

I am facing error as

```
@by_hidden.should_not_receive(:by_limit).with(100).and_return(@by_limit)
       (Double Object).by_limit(100)
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (100)
           received: 0 times with arguments: (100)
```

Any information on this shall be appreciated.

Comment: `should_not_receive` is deprecated, use `expect(...).not_to receive(...)`. Also, why do you set a return value if you don't want the method to be called? that `and_return` makes no sense.

Comment: Also -- Please try to provide a [mcve] in all questions, if possible. In this instance, a [mcve] would be: A full spec and a basic method implementation, which anyone else can run to get the same error you're showing us. This would only need to be about 5-10 lines of code.

Comment: 1. you should use the syntax that @arieljuod mentioned.   
2. Did you run the call ? If you are using `expect(..).not_to receive(...)` , you need to make the call afterwards resulting in writing the expect before the call:
`expect(..).not_to receive(...); do_the_call;`
If you want to have a "given, when, then" approach you need to use `expect(...).not_to have_received(...)` as is shown [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this:

```
expect(@by_hidden).not_to receive(:by_limit).with(100)
```

Or perhaps (depending on your use case) even just:

```
expect(@by_hidden).not_to receive(:by_limit)
```

---

1. It doesn't make sense to stub a return value, if you expect the method not be called.
2. The `expect(...).to` syntax has been preferred over `should`/`should_not`, for several years now. The latter approach can be problematic for certain types of object, so it's best to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion